# Web mobile app opening in browser but not in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have problem using webview. When I am opening web mobile url in android browser it is opening perfectly but when i am using webView it is not rendering any view and stuck displaying a progress bar.
I am using below code:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ctn_webview);
WebSettings webSetting = myWebView.getSettings();
webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSetting.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSetting.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSetting.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSetting.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/<my-app-pkg>/databases");
webSetting.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webSetting.setDatabasePath("/data/data/<my-app-pkg>/databases");
webSetting.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

webSetting.setAllowFileAccess(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);
```

Please note that the page is behind login credential so it redirects to many url in between to reach final page. The login page workes perfectly and after authentication i am redirected to final page where I see a round progress moving (image below). There it should render many buttons and form stuff.

Also when I am opening the same url in the browser in emulator it is working perfectly.
I dont know what I am missing. Please help.

[image: the page where I got stuck. It is not rendering the view.]

Comment: yes I tried on real device and getting the same result